# Proof $Z_t = e^{-(a+\frac{b^2}{2})t +X_t}$ is a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals

I want to prove that $E[Z_t|Z_s]=Z_s, 0<s<t$ and $Z_t, X_t$ defined as
$$
Z_t = e^{-(a+\frac{b^2}{2})t + X_t}\\
X_t = at + bB_t
$$
where $B_t \sim N(0, t)$ is Brownian motion, $a=\mu(x), b = \sigma(x)$, i.e. drift and volatility are constant.

First, I rewrote
\begin{align}
Z_t &= Z_s + (Z_t - Z_s) \Rightarrow\\
E[Z_t|Z_s] &= E[Z_s + (Z_t - Z_s)|Z_s] = E[Z_s|Z_s] + E[(Z_t-Z_s)|Z_s] \\
&= Z_s + E[(Z_t-Z_s)|Z_s]
\end{align}
The first term is $Z_s$ because conditional expectation of a random variable on itself is equal to the random variable. For the second term, I noticed that without the condition on $Z_s$, ( I set $e^{-(a+\frac{b^2}{2})t} = h(a,b,t)$)
$$
\frac{Z_t - Z_s}{h(a,b,s)} = h(a,b,t-s)e^{X_{t}} - e^{X_s}
$$
Without the $h(\cdot)$ term, I would expand the functions of $X_t$ using Taylor series up to the first term:
$$
e^{X_t} - e^{X_s} \approx (X_{t}-X_s)e^{X_s}
$$
so that $X_t -X_s \sim N(a(t-s), b^2(t-s))$ and $e^{X_{s}} \sim LogNormal(as, b^2)$, so if they're independent, then
$$
E[e^{X_t} - e^{X_s}] \approx a(t-s) \cdot as = a^2s(t-s)
$$
which is not equal to $0$, so $Z_t$ is not a martingale. But, as I said earlier, I'm not sure how to account for conditioning on $Z_s$ and how to add the $h(\cdot)$ term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your approach of setting $Z_t = Z_s + (Z_t - Z_s)$ may work for the Brownian motion, but fails in this case due to the multiplicative nature of the exponential, which leads to complications if you try to linearize.

Instead, go for the *multiplicative* kind of equality you would like : $Z_t = \frac{Z_t}{Z_s} Z_s$ (where these quotients are well defined a.s. since $Z_t$ is positive almost surely).

Then $E[Z_t|Z_s] = Z_sE[\frac{Z_t}{Z_s} |Z_s]$.

Write the expression for $\frac{Z_t}{Z_s}$, and see that it somehow only depends upon $B_t - B_s$. Now, $Z_s$ belongs in the sigma algebra of $B_s$, as it is a Borel function of $B_s$. Hence, by the independent increment property of Brownian motion, this variable is *independent* of $Z_s$, and therefore the above conditional expectation, is just the usual expectation, which should be $1$ once you get everything together and evaluate. (has to do with moment generating function of the normal random variable)

---

EDIT : $$\frac{Z_s}{Z_t} = e^{X_t - X_s - (a+\frac{b^2}{2})(t-s)} = e^{b(B_t - B_s) + a(t-s) - (a-\frac{b^2}{2})(t-s)} =e^{b(B_t-B_s) - \frac{b^2}{2}(t-s)} $$,

which is independent of $Z_s$, hence the conditional expecation is just the expectation of this. Now, $(B_t - B_s) \sim N(0,(t-s))$. Looking up the MGF of $N(\mu,\sigma)$, we have $E[e^{tN}] = e^{t \mu + \frac{t^2\sigma^2}{2}}$. For our case, $N(0,(t-s))$ and $t=b$, we have $E[e^{b(B_t - B_s)}] = e^{\frac{b^2(t-s)}{2}}$. That cancels out with whatever is left to give $1$.

Comment: How do you get $1$? I keep getting $-\frac{b^2}{2}t$

Comment: i will edit it and show you

Comment: Yes, now I see that! I got the expectation of LogNormal rv wrong!

Comment: btw why is the expression indep of $Z_s$? simply because it is solely a function of brownian motion and $s$?

Comment: The Brownian motion has the property of independent increments. Zt-Zs is a function of the increment and Zs is a function of Bs, so they are independent too.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $X_t$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu=at$ and variance $\sigma^2=b^2t$. Therefore, $e^{X_t}$ is log-normally distributed, with mean $e^{at+0.5\sigma^2}$. Therefore:

$$ Z_t:=e^{-at-0.5\sigma^2+X_t} $$

Must be a martingale, since $\forall t$:

$$\mathbb{E}[Z_t]=e^{0}=1=\mathbb{E}[Z_t|\mathcal{F}_0]=\mathbb{E}[Z_t|Z_0] $$

If you wan't to prove the martingale condition explicitely for some $s\leq t$, you can write:

$$\mathbb{E}[Z_t|Z_s]=\mathbb{E}\left[exp\left(-as-0.5b^2s+as+bW_s-a(t-s)-0.5b^2(t-s)+a(t-s)+bW(t-s) \right)|Z_s \right]=\\=Z_s\mathbb{E}[exp(-a(t-s)-0.5b^2(t-s)+a(t-s)+bW(t-s)]=\\=Z_s\mathbb{E}[exp(-a(h)-0.5b^2(h)+a(h)+bW(h)]=Z_s $$

The first line of the equality above uses the independence of increments property of the Brownian motion (i.e $W_t=W_s + W(t-s)$ in distribution). The last line evaluates to $Z_s$ with the expectation equal to 1, since again, $E[Z_t]=1$ $\forall t$.

Comment: Is $W_t$ the same as $B_t$, Brownian motion $N(0,t)$?

Comment: In the last line I keep getting LogNormal rv with mean $-\frac{tb^2}{2}$. How did you get $1$?

Comment: Yes, $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion with mean zero and variance $t$. The key is that $\mathbb{E}[e^{W_t}]=e^{0.5t}$ whilst $\mathbb{E}[e^{bW_t}]=e^{0.5b^2t}$. This is how log-normal distribution works: if $X\sim N(\mu , \sigma)$ then $e^X$ is LogNormal with mean $e^{\mu + 0.5 \sigma^2}$ and variance $(e^{\sigma^2}-1)(e^{2\mu+\sigma^2}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution